# Android Status bar crops menu

Tags: android, html, css, statusbar

That's probably a simple trick, our menu is `croped by the satus bar` on some `adroid devices` as you can see on this screenshot.

Any idea on how this could be solved ? Can it be related to `z-index` properties ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you have the following property on your layout, you need to set it to false:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

this stretches the active area of your app to cover the entire screen, so by setting it to false, it should start that area, right below the status bar. If not, would you please provide your layout code for reference?

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure what you mean by layout. The website is setup as a progressive web app, but otherwise it's just basic html, css and php responsive website. It's not an adroid app. Would i be able to add your line of code somewhere ?

Comment: My mistake. Not sure I could be of help in this scenario. I guess one a solution would be to request a fullscreen mode in your web app manifest. Maybe this link could provide more info :https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/